# sh: irb not found error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am very new to Ruby on rails . while running script/console ,
i am getting the below environment ..

aruna@aruna-desktop:~/railsprojects/pagesapp$ script/console
   Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
   sh: irb: not found

Please give suggestions..

Comment: Post what environment you're working in please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*thelepaty_mode: it looks like you using Ubuntu, so

```
sudo apt-get install irb
```

will help you

Answer (score 4):

I believe `irb` is in a separate package (called `irb`, IIRC), so you'll need to install that as well.